# C# download file from web using URL and xpath

Tags: c#, xpath, html-parsing, webclient

I'd like to download the daily photo from this [site](http://photography.nationalgeographic.com/photography/photo-of-the-day/) but i can't use the JPEG's URL because it changes everyday.

Is there any way to download object from site using the page URL and XPath? I tried to find some method in WebClient but with no luck.

Comment: try to download the html file, isolate the `primary_photo` class and from there on out isolate the `img` tag. Then you can get the `src` and download it directly.

Comment: It's possible using HTMLAgilityPack (you can get it from nuget)

Comment: Yep, I agree with @Nasreddine. HTMLAgility should do nice here. The image url seems to be in the only `<link rel="canonical"` element. Should be easy enough to get that with an XPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of my comment with [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com) :

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string resource = client.DownloadString("http://photography.nationalgeographic.com/photography/photo-of-the-day/");
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(resource);
var imgDiv = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(@class,'primary_photo')]");
var imgSrc = imgDiv.SelectSingleNode("//img/@src");
string relativePath = imgSrc.GetAttributeValue("src", "");
```

Comment: Thank You, although `imgDiv.SelectSingleNode("//img/@src")` goes to first matching element, not first element in imgDiv node, You have to use whole path in one place `var imgSrc = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='primary_photo']//img/@src")` more info [here](http://codefall.io/15-jun-2014/htmlagilitypack-getting-started.html) Digging Deep section

Comment: Or rather `var imgSrc = imgDiv.SelectSingleNode(".//img/@src");` Note the dot before //. That will select the first matching node that is a descendant of that imgDiv node.

Comment: You're right @LocEngineer, it's clearer solution